# Cron job that checks for date expiration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron

Let's take the following example:

I have two `mongoDb` collections named `user` and `products`. A user can add unlimited products, but each product expires in 5 days and it has to be dynamically removed from the db when it expires.

user.js

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    timezone: { type: String },
    products: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Products' }]
  }
)

export default mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

products.js

```
var RunSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    completedAt: { type: Date }
  }
)

export default mongoose.model('Run', RunSchema);
```

Is there another way of doing this in nodejs rather than having one `cron job` which runs every day and checks all documents from the `products` collection?

I'm thinking about a solution where a each user can have a cron job that starts once they add a product...

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-cron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is too late answer the question even though , I would like to give alternative operation with minimal operation and **without Cron Job**

If you want remove product document after creation of 5 day's interval then you can achieve with 2 line of code in model itself.
You have add one property i.e(**expireAt**) in model and pass the interval to that property with help of **moment npm library**

```
    var RunSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    completedAt: { type: Date },
    expireAt: {
         type: Date,
         default: moment(new Date()).add("5", "days"),
         expires: 432000000
   }
  }
)

export default mongoose.model('Run', RunSchema);
```

after creation of  product document date and time . it will automatically remove document from collection of every 5 days of interval.

Answer (score 1):

First method:

You can add a cron in NodeJs and it will execute your task every x

Example:

Add the package [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) in your project.

```
npm i cron -S
```

Create a file cron.js

```
'use strict';

 let express = require('express'),
 CronJob = require('cron').CronJob,
 moment = require('moment'),
 mongoose = require('mongoose');
 Collection = mongoose.model('Collection');

var collection = {

    clean : function() {
        // Each hour
        new CronJob('0 * * * *', function() {

          console.log("Hello I'm Cron!");

           // Delete all the product expired of your db
           // Your code ...

        }, null, true, 'Europe/Paris');
    }

}

module.exports = {
    init : function() {
        return (
            collection.clean()
        )
    }
}
```

In your server.js, add the following code to initialize the cron

```
/**
 * Init cron tasks
 */

var cron = require('./cron');
cron.init()
```

Second method:

Setting expiry time in your model, check that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596796/mongoose-expire-data-but-keep-in-database) for more informations.

Comment: The second method seems to be exactly what I need, but when a product expires I will also have to remove its reference from the `user` collection ... any ideas how can I do that using this method?

Comment: In the answer linked, you have a beginning of answer, rework your 2 models and add extra check or executions.